# cannot set modal background to transparent in android

Tags: modal-dialog, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

cannot set the background of the native script modal window to transparent

i have done a example in the below link. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=6xzzC2

```
<!-- >> modal-view-xml -->
<Page backgroundColor="transparent" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
    shownModally="onShownModally" height="300" width="250">

    <StackLayout borderRadius="30" backgroundColor="green">
        <Label text="android" textWrap="true" />
        <Label text="android" textWrap="true" />
        <Label text="android" textWrap="true" />
        <Label text="android" textWrap="true" />
        <Label text="android" textWrap="true" />
        <Label text="android" textWrap="true" />
        <Label text="android" textWrap="true" />
    </StackLayout>

</Page>
<!-- << modal-view-xml -->
```

i need a border rounded modal window

Comment: iOS modal windows are fullscreen by default, it's not possible to modify that behaviour. You might have to build your own modal like View if you still prefer one.

Comment: @Manoj sorry for not to mention that i'm trying for android. this code was not at all working for android.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (page._dialogFragment) {
    page._dialogFragment.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=6xzzC2&v=2)